# Wildfly 30.. websocket server endpoint not working

Tags: wildfly

Migrated from Wildfly 23 to 30 and websocket server endpoint doesn't work!

I'm using out of the box standalone.xml.

The WEB content loads fine on http/https (SSL was set up with built-in letsencrypt)

/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web >
   
   <context-root>/</context-root>  
   <enable-websockets>true</enable-websockets>
   <virtual-host>WebApp1</virtual-host>
      
</jboss-web>
```

standalone.xml

```
   <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="ssl-context-36669590-7d69-4fed-aa77-fd7b2705472c" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
            </host>
            <host name="app1" alias="app1.co,www.app1.co"/>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong or what I'm missing.

I've even enabled ufw to allow traffic. Still, the connection does not work.

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Postfix                    ALLOW       Anywhere
6001/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3389                       ALLOW       Anywhere
Postfix (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
6001/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3389 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: how do you know it's not working?

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'wss://app1.co/api' failed:

Comment: Did you migrate your source from `javax` to `jakarta`?